# How to re-size avd to real device size?

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Hie, i guess am asking silly question here, but am really confused with the avd things.
firstly i wanted to test my application on Samsung Galaxy Ace, as i could not find actual simulator for the device. Are there any simulators for actual devices available online???

I added its skin to my AVD and used following configuration:

**Target:API Level 8**

**SD Card:  size: 512mb**

**Skin:   Built In: HVGA**

**Hardware:  Abstracted LCD Density: 160**

During Launching the AVD i checked 'Scale display to real size' and set

**size=3.5 and monitor dpi =96(as my monitor size is 1024x768)**

(if i uncheck then i get real big emulator)
but i don't get my avd as per my original device size.
also my skinned emulator has icons overlapped and i cannot run my app on it properly.
[image]

Am really confused about this size thing, can anyone help about how to get real device sized emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally its solved, i changed the hw.lcd.density and the problem is solved :)